# Matlab - Waitbar with marquee style

Tags: matlab, user-interface

**Problem**

I'm looking for a improved waitbar in matlab that supports for marquee style.

**Sample syntax I'd like to have:**

```
smartWaitbar(6/12, 'Step 7/12...'); % Ratio € [0.0 1.0] ==> Normal display
smartWaibar(NaN, 'Connecting to database...'); % ratio = NaN ==> Marquee style
```

**Sample display I'd like to have:**

[image]

NB1: I searched [file-exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=waitbar&term=waitbar) but did not found what i was looking for.

NB2: If it does not exist yet, I'll probably create my own waitbar using [winforms](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/616-how-to-create-windows-forms-in-matlab).

Comment: here's another link just in case: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-status-bar-components

Comment: @natan Thanks, this seems perfect, now just need to embed this with `jprogressbar.setIndeterminate(true)` ... great

Comment: I converted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the entry about setting status-bar components in Yair Altmans blog "undocumented Matlab" http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-status-bar-components

Comment: For information, I pasted code and usage example for a 'SmartWaitbar' [>> here <<](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/f4a616e23eeb2fd48fcd). May required more validation on user inputs or code refactoring, anyhow suits my needs for now.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **mywaitbar** on matlab central file exchange. I created this waitbar just to add customized modes to the waitbar.

You can find the code at:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46896-mywaitbar

Click on the description's image to see it in action.

I solved the "cirular scroll" or "marquee style" with a timer function that updates the position of the bar, depending on the figure handle passed to the timer function and the number of timer steps that have been done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal ;) ... You may have a look to the one I've created for passing parameters as key/value pairs (to update 1 to many parameters easily) + special ratio = NaN (to go to marquee style) : https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/f4a616e23eeb2fd48fcd#file-smartwaitbar-m